# Change element's background-color style on button click with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just made a quick and simple test where my user has an option to select answers to specific questions by ticking the html tickbox. I'd like to provide a feature for user to click on a specific button to change background-color style of the correct answers to green, so the user can know if he answered correctly.

I've tried multiple javascript-based codes that can be found on the very first few pages of google.

```
<style>
#ca {
background-color:white;
}
</style>
<b>My question:</b>
<l>
        <li id="ca"><input type="checkbox"> Answer 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"> Answer 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"> Answer 3</li>
    <li id="ca"><input type="checkbox"> Answer 4</li>
</l>
    <button type="button"
    onclick="document.getElementById('ca').style.background-color = 'green'">
    Show me the correct answers.</button>
```

Correct answers are specified with Element ID 'ca'.

I'd like to change background-color of elements with ID 'ca' on button click.

Comment: You can’t use duplicate IDs. Using `id="ca"` twice is invalid. Use classes instead. Also, `background-color` isn’t a valid identifier. Use `backgroundColor`.

Comment: and you should use camelCase for properties with dash in them, so you should change code to  style.backgroundColor

Comment: I have just tried using classes aswell. I used getElementByClassName and assigned class 'ca' to each correct answer. However, clicking on a button does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with the duplicated IDs:

> #### [`Element.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)
>
> If the id value is not the empty string, it must be unique in a document

Embrace the function [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for binding events, it's fancy and more clear for testing, reading code, Etc.

*This approach uses a style `cans` which adds a green background when the button is clicked.*

```js
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.ca')).forEach(function(e) {
    e.classList.add('cans');
  });
});
```

```css
.cans {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<b>My question:</b>
<l>
  <li class="ca"><input type="checkbox"> Answer 1</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox"> Answer 2</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox"> Answer 3</li>
  <li class="ca"><input type="checkbox"> Answer 4</li>
</l>
<button id='myButton' type="button">
    Show me the correct answers.</button>
```

Comment: It gives me this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: @JohnWill did you realize that button has an id?

Comment: Yes, I did. @Ele

Comment: @JohnWill that's weird, it must work.  I think you have a problem either in your js code or in your markup because the code snippet works smoothly.

Comment: I just tried using that code on codepen.io snippet and it worked. However, it does not work on my web-page. What could possibly cause it not to work on my web-page? Here's the snippet if you would like to take a look: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/romyOa

Comment: @JohnWill got it, you need to put your script below of the HTML because at that moment the HTML is not completed rendered.  Or, you can use the event [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

Comment: It worked! Awesome. I assumed it's something like that but didn't have exactly that on mind to test it. Thank you very much Ele.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var chkbox = document.getElementsByClassName("chkbox");
var x = document.getElementById("mylist");

function onChangeListener() {

 
    for (var i = 0; i < chkbox.length; i++) {

        if (chkbox[i].checked) {
 
x.getElementsByClassName("ca")[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
         
        }
else{x.getElementsByClassName("ca")[i].style.backgroundColor = "";}
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<b>My question:</b>
<l id="mylist">
        <li id="ca" class="ca"><input type="checkbox" class="chkbox"> Answer 1</li>
    <li id="ca" class="ca"><input type="checkbox" class="chkbox"> Answer 2</li>
    <li id="ca" class="ca"><input type="checkbox" class="chkbox"> Answer 3</li>
    <li id="ca" class="ca"><input type="checkbox" class="chkbox"> Answer 4</li>
</l>
   <button onclick="onChangeListener()">
    Show me the correct answers.</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The snippet only colorizes the first correct answer, regardless of how many of them are there, and there are multiple.

Comment: Try to Check it now.